# What are the advantages of 人类将如何演变 over 人性会怎么改变?

Tags: word-choice

I'm analyzing [Writing critique request: Zhou Ziwang and the revolutionary new technology](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/35746/writing-critique-request-zhou-ziwang-and-the-revolutionary-new-technology) and in particular these two sentences:

> Intended English meaning:  How will mankind change?
>   My writing: [人性](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BA%BA%E6%80%A7)会怎么[改变](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%94%B9%E5%8F%98)？
>   [Toosky Hierot](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/35749/8099): [人类](http://youdao.com/w/%E4%BA%BA%E7%B1%BB)将如何[演变](http://youdao.com/w/%E6%BC%94%E5%8F%98)？

The context is that a revolutionary new technology has been discovered, and people are worried about its implications for the future.  Thus, out of concern, they ask rhetorical questions like: *How will mankind change?*

**Question**: What are the advantages of 人类将如何演变 over 人性会怎么改变?

This seems to be my impression:

- 人性 = "humanity" whereas 人类 = "mankind", so 人类 is accurate.
- I'm not seeing a major benefit to 将 = "will" over 会 = "would" (relevant question: [Talking future tense: 将，要，将要， 会， 将会](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/23237/talking-future-tense-%e5%b0%86-%e8%a6%81-%e5%b0%86%e8%a6%81-%e4%bc%9a-%e5%b0%86%e4%bc%9a)).
- I believe 怎么 and 如何 are interchangeable in this case (relevant question: [What is the difference between 怎么 and 如何？](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/1255/what-is-the-difference-between-%e6%80%8e%e4%b9%88-and-%e5%a6%82%e4%bd%95))
- 演变 = "evolve" whereas 改变 = "change".  I'm not clear about which is better here, but perhaps 改变 is closer to "edit" (?).

Please let me know what I understand correctly/incorrectly.

Comment: It's ambiguous in your context. You might want to explain what you mean by "how will mankind change?" in English.

Comment: Arh, it's important to note that I rephrased my translation to meet Chinese aesthetics, so it's not exactly the word translation of the excerpt.

Comment: In any case, it seems 人类 is definitely better than 人性, and I'm yet to reveal what the technology actually is, but 演变 might actually be better than 改变.  But you'll have to wait for the sequels for that: I'll try to write the next part taking on board what I've managed to learn from the first part.

Comment: @Becky李蓓 Then just go for it.ｸﾞｯ!(๑•̀ㅂ•́)و✧

Comment: @Becky李蓓 Another point is that, it's more elegant to use verb phrases than adjectives. E.g. 这种技术有违自然>这种技术不自然>这种技术是不自然的。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 人性会怎么改变  vs. 人类将如何演变

- 人性 mainly refers to " human morality". 人性会怎么改变 means "how will humankind's morality be changed by this technology?  We see many examples of technology changes human's behavior and moral value. If it is your main concern, you should choose 人性 over 人类
- 人类 mainly refers to "the human kind" in a broad sense. That includes biological and mental aspects. If this technology changes not only human's mind, but also body, then you should use 人类 over 人性
- 会(would) and 将(will) are both valid in this sentence.
- 怎么 and 如何 means the same, just 怎么 is more colloquial and 如何 is more literary
- 改变 = change; 演变 = evolve. A technology no matter how advance, it is not likely to change humankind  biologically. 改变 should be the right choice.

Base on your main concern (human morality vs. biological and mental change) you can choose to write:

- 人性会怎么改变?/ 人性将怎么改变?/ 人性会如何改变?
- 人类将如何改变?/ 人类会如何改变?

*You can replace 将 or 会 with 将会*

Comment: @Becky 李蓓  So, what is the main concern?

Comment: I don't want to spoil the story... but it's definitely more biological than mental.